# How do I group lines of strings separated by empty lines using java stream

Tags: java, functional-programming

I have the following input and I would like them to be grouped using the empty line as the logical divider.
input datatype:
`List<String>`

```
line1
line2
line3

line4
line5
line6

line7
line8
```

expected output:
type: List<List>

```
{{line1, line2, line3}, {line4, line5, line6}, {line7, line8}}
```

While this is trivial using imperative programming, I am looking for a solution that uses functional programming in Java.

Comment: Is your input a single string or a list of string or a text file or something else?

Comment: the input is a List<String>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say what Java version you are using, but this should work in Java8+. The `reduce` function on `stream` can give you what you want if you use the one with 3 args an initial value in this case a list with lists of string, a lambda function that takes the current result and a single string. This really does all the work of adding a new list when it sees a blank line. Finally, a combiner that explains how to combine 2 lists but is really just to help the compiler understand what is going on. In this case it does nothing but that so it can always return an empty list.

```java
String input = "line1\n" +
        "line2\n" +
        "line3\n" +
        "\n" +
        "line4\n" +
        "line5\n" +
        "line6\n" +
        "\n" +
        "line7\n" +
        "line8";
List<String> strings = Arrays.stream(input.split("\n")).collect(Collectors.toList());

List<List<String>> initial = new ArrayList<>();
initial.add(new ArrayList<>());
List<List<String>> result = strings.stream().reduce(initial, (subtotal, element) -> {
    if (element.trim().isEmpty()) {
        subtotal.add(new ArrayList<>());
    } else {
        subtotal.get(subtotal.size() - 1).add(element);
    }
    return subtotal;

}, (list1, list2) -> emptyList());
```

I get the output of a `List<List<String>>` of result[[line1, line2, line3], [line4, line5, line6], [line7, line8]] which I believe is what you are after.

Comment: Sorry, it didn't seem to work. do you have the print out?

Comment: @Mox what did you need to change? I can update the answer for others.

Comment: I have edited your answer. not too sure if you can see it

Answer (score 2):

It can be done by splitting the list into sublist by the known empty string as a separator:

```
List<String> data = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "", "d", "", "e", "f");

int[] indexes = 
                Stream.of(
                  IntStream.of(-1), 
                  IntStream.range(0, data.size()).filter(i -> data.get(i).isEmpty()), 
                  IntStream.of(data.size())
                ) 
                .flatMapToInt(ix -> ix)
                .toArray();
List<List<String>> subSets = 
          IntStream.range(0, indexes.length - 1)
                   .mapToObj(i -> data.subList(indexes[i] + 1, indexes[i + 1]))
                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
subSets.forEach(System.out::println);
```

The output is:

```
[a, b, c]
[d]
[e, f]
```

Or it can be implemented via re-joining and re-splitting the input data (if the input is `List<String>`):

```
List<String> data = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "", "d", "", "e", "f");

Arrays.stream(
    data.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.joining("\n")).split("\n{2}") // split by double 'empty lines'
)
.map(s -> Arrays.stream(s.split("\n")).collect(Collectors.toList()))
.collect(Collectors.toList())
.forEach(System.out::println);
```

The output is the same as above.

Comment: your second approach is error prone. the assumption is that there those `##` or `####` will not appear in the line.

Comment: Yes, such assumption was made based on the test data.  Though, I replaced these custom separators with `\n` in the update.